# DotNetNuke 9 dnnConfirm dialog error

Tags: jquery, asp.net, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module, dotnetnuke-9

It seems that since DotNetNuke 9 the build-in confirm dalog `dnnConfirm` does not work anymore like it did before or has been removed. The error is `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dnnConfirm is not a function`

I uses it like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.DeleteButton').each(function (index, item) {
        $(this).dnnConfirm({
            text: 'Delete this item?',
                yesText: 'Yes',
                noText: 'No',
                title: 'Delete Dialog',
                width: 400,
                isButton: false
            });
        });
</script>
```

I looked it up in the documentation, but could not find anything.

- http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/dnnconfirm-jquery-plugin
- http://uxguide.dotnetnuke.com/UIPatterns/ConfirmDialog.html

Does anyone have a fix/workaround/solution?

**UPDATE**

I just found out the function *is* present when you log in as a SuperUser but not as a visitor or normal user who is logged in. This would indicate that some JS files are only loaded when SuperUser whereas they were always present in previous versions.

Comment: Does it throw a JS error now?

Comment: Quick search of the REPO still seems there are a lot of dnnconfirm references in the DNN9 source code

Comment: Yes, error `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dnnConfirm is not a function`. I've added it to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has been identified and a solution has been found. The file that was missing on the client side was `dnn.jquery.js`. In older versions of DNN (< 7.3) it was added by calling `DotNetNuke.Framework.jQuery.RequestDnnPluginsRegistration();` in code behind.

But since version 7.3 it has been replaced with `JavaScript.RequestRegistration`

```
using DotNetNuke.Framework.JavaScriptLibraries;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    JavaScript.RequestRegistration(CommonJs.DnnPlugins);
}
```